# Compute a Python Program to to display the following output with the original 13 states in alphabetical order

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop

The file `States.txt` contains the 50 U.S. states in the order in which they joined the union. Write a program, using the `for` loop, to display the following output with the original 13 states in alphabetical order.

**Content inside the file States.txt:**

```
Delaware
Pennsylvania
New Jersey
Georgia
Connecticut
Massachusetts
Maryland
South Carolina
New Hampshire
Virginia
New York
North Carolina
Rhode Island
Vermont
Kentucky
Tennessee
Ohio
Louisiana
Indiana
Mississippi
Illinois
Alabama
Maine
Missouri
Arkansas
Michigan
Florida
Texas
Iowa
Wisconsin
California
Minnesota
Oregon
Kansas
West Virginia
Nevada
Nebraska
Colorado
North Dakota
South Dakota
Montana
Washington
Idaho
Wyoming
Utah
Oklahoma
New Mexico
Arizona
Alaska
Hawaii
```

**My current coding:**

```py
infile = open("States.txt", 'r')
states = [line.rstrip() for line in infile]
states.sort()      # I sort those 50 states in alphabetical order first
for state in states:
    print("\r", states[6],"\n",states[7], "\n", states[9], "\n", states[19], "\n", states[20], "\n", states[28], "\n", states[29], "\n", states[31], "\n", states[32], "\n", states[37], "\n", states[38], "\n", states[39], "\n", states[45], end="")   #I locate exact position of those 13 states
    break
infile.close()
```

Although I can display the expected output using the above coding , it is definitely not a good way to utilize the `for` loop function as I can still display the exact result without the `for` loop statement.

**The expected output for the program:** (the 13 states are needed to be displayed in a vertical way)

```
Connecticut
Delaware
Georgia
Maryland
Massachusetts
New Hampshire
New Jersey
New York
North Carolina
Pennsylvania
Rhode Island
South Carolina
Virginia
```

Comment: First create a list with the first 13 states (can be done with a for-loop) and then sort this list.

Comment: Consider the edge case where some states have **New**, **North**, **South**, and consist of more than a single word. Your text file provides no comma separation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [slicing](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) to take the first 13 entries of `states` before sorting:

```
infile = open("States.txt", 'r')
states = [line.rstrip() for line in infile]
original_states = states[:13]
original_states.sort()
for state in original_states:
    print(state)
infile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

So if the first list contains 50 states, and you should output 13 of them in a sorted order, I guess you could make a list containing the 13 key states, and in your for loop, you could check if a state is one of them, and only if true print it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.islice` to read only the first 13 lines of the file before sorting them:

```
from itertools import islice
with open('States.txt') as infile:
    print(*sorted(islice(infile, 13)), sep='')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my first contribution to stackoverflow so please go easy on me. I want to get more involved and give back because I have been helped greatly by this community.

Someone probably can simplify this more, but this is my solution:

```
filename="States.txt"
states= list()

with open (filename) as file:
    # convert to list of names 
    items = list(file.read().split())
```

Generate list of state names from the file. Because the file contains space separated names, you need to keep some names together: e.g. New York

```
two_word_state_names=['New','North','South','West', 'Rhode']
skip=False

for idx,item in enumerate(items):
    if skip:
        skip=False
        continue
    elif item in two_word_state_names:
        states.append(str(items[idx] + " " + items[idx+1]))
        skip=True # skip the next loop because next item is the second word of the state
    else:
        states.append(item)
```

Now you can sort and print the first thirteen:

```
thirteen_states=states[:13]
thirteen_states.sort()

# Print result
for state in thirteen_states:
    print (state)
```

```
Connecticut
Delaware
Georgia
Maryland
Massachusetts
New Hampshire
New Jersey
New York
North Carolina
Pennsylvania
Rhode Island
South Carolina
Virginia
```

Answer (score 0):

Your original question had the states as space-separated words, which required extra logic to extract and represent the two-word states. With your edited question, it is much simpler:

```
with open ('States.txt') as file:
    states = list(file.read().split('\n')[:13])
    states.sort()

for state in states:
    print (state)
```

```
Connecticut
Delaware
Georgia
Maryland
Massachusetts
New Hampshire
New Jersey
New York
North Carolina
Pennsylvania
Rhode Island
South Carolina
Virginia
```

Comment: You could probably delete this answer since all the information looks to be contained in your other answer (which looks useful)